# Login with username or email with Cakephp 3

Tags: email, authentication, cakephp-3.0

I want to do a login with username or email. So I want to change Auth fields dynamically.

How can I modify $this->Auth fields as Cakehp 2 did?

In cakephp 2 you could do:

```php
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'Form' => array(
        'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'),
    ),
);
```

I've tried to change authenticate like this but it doesn't work:

```php
$this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
    'Form' => [
        'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password']
    ]
]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Whoever finds this: the link @ndm posted has the answer. Just go to that page and Ctrl+F `email`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've found the solution!

I assumed that username is alphaNumeric (letters and numbers).

Remember to add `$this->Auth->constructAuthenticate();`

AppController.php

```php
use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Core\Configure;

class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action'     => 'index'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action'     => 'login'
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

UsersController.php

```php
use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Validation\Validation;

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            if (Validation::email($this->request->data['username'])) {
                $this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
                    'Form' => [
                        'fields' => ['username' => 'email']
                    ]
                ]);
                $this->Auth->constructAuthenticate();
                $this->request->data['email'] = $this->request->data['username'];
                unset($this->request->data['username']);
            }

            $user = $this->Auth->identify();

            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }

            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
}
```

login.ctp

```php
<div class="form">
<?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Please enter your username and password') ?></legend>
        <?= $this->Form->input('username') ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('password') ?>
    </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you have to add anything else to your UsersController to make it work?  When I try this, I get "Fatal error: Class 'App\Controller\Validation' not found" on the "if (Validation::email(..." line.

Comment: Found it: add "use Cake\Validation\Validation;" to the top of the UsersController and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

**AppController.php** load Auth component.

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize' => 'Controller',
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'userModel' => 'Users',
            ]
        ],
        ...
    ]);
```

**UsersController.php**

Note: identify() method

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        //$user = $this->Auth->identify();
        $user = $this->Users->identify($this->request->data);
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect'), [
                'key' => 'auth'
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

**UsersTable.php**

*Assuming that **email** and **username** columns are in same table.*

```
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;

public function identify($formData) {

        $passOk = false;
        $user = $this->find()->hydrate(false)->where(['email' => $formData['email']])->orWhere(['username' => $formData['email']])->first();
        $checker = new DefaultPasswordHasher;
        if(!is_null($passOk))
            $passOk = $checker->check($formData['password'], $user['password']); 

        return $passOk ? $user  : null;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**log in with the username Or Email its Perfect Work just try it.**

UsersController.php

```php
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        if(!filter_var($this->request->data['username'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)===false){
            $this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
                'Form'=>['fields'=>['username'=>'email', 'password'=>'password']]
            ]);
            $this->Auth->constructAuthenticate();
            $this->request->data['email']=$this->request->data['username'];
            unset($this->request->data['username']);
        }
        pr($this->request->data);

        $user=$this->Auth->identify();
        if($user){
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            $this->Flash->success(__('Wel Come-'.ucfirst($user['name'])));
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another useful solution (perhaps)...

**login.ctp**

> To make your life easy, for the *user input* just use **username** and **password**

```php
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
     <div class="panel-body">
         <div class="form-group">
             <?= $this->Form->control('username', // <-- username input
               ['type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false, 
                    'placeholder' => __('Username Or Email') ]) ?>
             <?= $this->Form->control('password',  // <-- password input
               ['class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => 
                    __('Password')]) ?>
                        </div>
             <?= $this->Form->button('ログイン', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block']) ?>
     </div>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

**UsersTable.php**

> Here is the place where we create checking for columns (**username** or **email**).
>   While, for **password checking**, its already taken care by CakePHP, no need to include it here.

```php
use Cake\ORM\Query;  

public function findAuth(Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query->where([
            'OR' => [ //<-- we use OR operator for our SQL
                'username' => $options['username'], //<-- username column
                'email' => $options['username'] //<-- email column
            ]], [], true); // <-- true here means overwrite original query !IMPORTANT. 

    return $query;
}
```

**AppController.php** load Auth component.

```php
public function initialize()
{
     parent::initialize();
     $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'finder' => 'auth' //<-- here we call our findAuth methods
                ]
            ],
     ]);
}
```

That's all. Happy coding.

**All the best!**

> **CakePHP 3 reference:** https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#customizing-find-query