# Login with username or email with Cakephp 4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

This is a follow-up question to [Login with username or email with Cakephp 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648852/login-with-username-or-email-with-cakephp-3): Is it possible to first check if a user is found by username and if not try to find the username by email?

The solution outlined in the answers to that question don't work anymore in cakephp-4, because they rely on manipulating the request object like this: `$this->request->data['email'] = $this->request->data['username'];`. This is no longer possible in cakephp-4.

Is there a way to authenticate the user without having to manipulate the request-object? The only thing I can think of is to have some javascript that copies the contents of the username-input into a hidden email-input, so that the email-field is set in the request without having to manipulate the request on the server-side. However this seems like a really hacky, fragile solution.

Comment: Read: https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html

Comment: @Salines The app I am working on still uses the AuthComponent (I know it is deprecated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the AuthComponent I use Tools.MultiColumn ( https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/docs/Auth/MultiColumn.md ) which works still fine.

See e.g. https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-sandbox/blob/master/src/Controller/AppController.php#L57

For the Auth plugin the better option is to use an array for the config as described in the plugin docs:

> fields: The fields for the lookup. Default is ['username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password']. You can also set the username to an array. For e.g. using ['username' => ['username', 'email'], 'password' => 'password'] will allow you to match value of either username or email columns.